# Filling Out Python Table and Emailing

Tags: python, email, tabular

Is there a way to create a table like the one below and fill it out with certain variables that I have created in my code and sending that table in an email?

Please see picture below:

[image: Table with name values]

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ways exists. There are probably two good ways and both are easy.

Docu : https://code.google.com/archive/p/prettytable/wikis/Tutorial.wiki

Like this its pretty easy to create tables in desired format. That lib is available via pip and really easy to use.

Two Format-output-types are available
 - ASCII-Style
 - HTML-Style

I guess that should fit your needs. HF